# class in Zend Framework isn't findable as soon as i add an Namespace to it

Tags: php, sql, namespaces, zend-framework2

im trying to build an little webpage with Zendframework using the "SqlQueue" class. The Files im using are working fine as long as im having them outside ZendFramework. As soon as i get them into zend, replace the Include with an namespace, it won't find an class.

```
//not working:
namespace Test\Model;    
class api{
    public function __construct(){
      $this->shortLimitQueue = new SplQueue();
      $this->longLimitQueue = new SplQueue();
    }
}

//working:
class api{
   public function __construct(){
      $this->shortLimitQueue = new SplQueue();
      $this->longLimitQueue = new SplQueue();
   }
}
```

if i do it without the namespace the class SqlQueue is findable... i also tried including the "api" file  externally but that won't work (same problem: he can't find the class SqlQueue as soon as i add an namespace to it. If i let the namespace out, i can't call the api class, but the SqlQueue works fine...

Edit: Using Zend Framework 2.6 with PHP 5.6.21 on CentOS 6.3

Answer (score 0):

When your namespace is set (i.e. namespace Test\Model), ZendFramework search the class in this namespace.
In your case, you may write :

```
$this->shortLimitQueue = new \SplQueue();
```

to force to search the class in Php core.

Comment: Or you could add `use SplQueue;`